# Get JSON array without dictionary?

Tags: ios

I've got an array in a JSON which I'm trying to receive. However I can only find examples showing how to get this kind of array:

```
[
{
    "text": "Pain Intensity", 
    "question_number": 1, 
    "id": 1
},
```

but my array is in this format:

```
[

    [1, "http://youtu.be/Ow9MjI25fYE", "video", "text here"],

    [2, "http://gardenwebs.net/Butchart.gardens.jpg", "image", "text here"]

]
```

Is there a way to get this? Or do I need to change my JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking you have assigned value to a variable x,

In first way, to get value, `"Pain Intensity"` you write, `x[0].text`

In second method, to get value `1`, `x[0][0]` and to get `"[http://youtu.be/Ow9MjI25fYE", "video", "text here"]` you have to write `x[0][1]`

First type is written in mixture of array and object.
2nd method is pure array.

But note that both are JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON you show is an array of arrays. There is no logical or code difference to downloading and parsing this compared to an array of dictionaries. The differences only arise with how you process the data once it has been parsed and you try to access it (iteration and by key).